# someone knows how to create the next CDATA xml structure in java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, cdata

i need create next structure en xml

```
<ser:myobjet soapenv: encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<xml xsi:type='xsd.string'>
    <!^[CDATA[<!xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <object>
            <service>
                <request>
                    <idservice>65445</idservice>
                    <date>14-08-2016</date>
                    <additionalData>
                        <user>user</user>
                        <city>mycity</city>
                    </additionalData>
                </request>
            </service>
        </object>]]>
</xml>
```

See I have a father and his children, yet one of them has their own children

```
                <request>
                    <idservice>65445</idservice>
                    <date>14-08-2016</date>
                    <additionalData>
                        <user>user</user>
                        <city>mycity</city>
                    </additionalData>
                </request>
```

I'm really lost and do not know how to create that structure.

Someone knows or some example of how to create it?

As I return a CDATA me and I need access to those tags, any idea how to do it?

Thank you.